# RadWindow has no titlebar

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-window

i have a multipage containing an ascx page which has a tab with 3 tabstrips. in one of the tabs pageview, i have a radgrid that contains a view column that opens a radwindow containing a gridview. myproblem is that all the radwindows open correctly until i open that tab's pageview, the window appears without it's title bar and border.

this is my window manager:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager runat="server" ID="RadWindowManager1" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false">
  <Windows>
    <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="ViewForm.aspx?IdVoiture=10&IdType=4">
    </telerik:RadWindow>
    <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com">
    </telerik:RadWindow>
</Windows>
 </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

and this is the javascript that opens my radwindow:

```
function OpenViewRepport(VID,TID) 
    {

         var oWindow3 = $find("RadWindowManager1").open("ViewForm.aspx?IdVoiture="+VID+"&IdType="+TID, null, null, 750, 600); 
}
```

please help me i tried all the ways to show the title bar but it doesnt appear. 
i think it is due to the fact that it is located in the multipage or because it is a ascx page.
note that the initial page containing the multipage also contains a windowmanager.

Comment: i have figured out what is the problem, there was some css files interfeering with the form of the radwindow.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function OpenWindow() {
        var url = '<%= ResolveUrl("add your url") %>';
        var wnd = window.radopen('', null);

        wnd.set_modal(true);
        wnd.set_visibleTitlebar(true);

        wnd.set_title(websiteName);
        wnd.setSize(600, 500);
        wnd.set_animation('Telerik.Web.UI.WindowAnimation.FlyIn');

        wnd.setUrl(url);

        return false;
    }
```

You can open window like above javascript code.and its works.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AddRecord.gif"
                OnClientClick="return OpenWindow();" />
```